# How to print a multidimensional array using for?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to print information from a multidimensional array using this code:

```
$url = $_POST['fromtheformandworking'];
$urls_array = get_headers($url,1);

$count_location = count($urls_array["Location"]);

for ($i=0; $i > $count_location ; $i++) { 
echo $urls_array["Location"]["$i"];
}
```

It's not returning anything. Does anyone have any idea where I'm doing wrong?

The function which tracks all http responses from the web server outputs:

```
Array
     (
       [0] => HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
[Date] => Array
    (
        [0] => Fri, 29 May 2015 10:38:17 GMT
        [1] => Fri, 29 May 2015 10:38:18 GMT
        [2] => Fri, 29 May 2015 10:38:18 GMT
        [3] => Fri, 29 May 2015 10:38:19 GMT
    )

[Server] => Array
    (
        [0] => Apache
        [1] => Apache
        [2] => Apache
        [3] => Apache
    )

[Location] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://www.cfcarehospitalar.com.br/produtos/cadeira-de-rodas-avd-aluminio-reclinavel-ortobras/
        [1] => http://www.cfcarehospitalar.com.br/cadeira-de-rodas-avd-aluminio-reclinavel.html.html
        [2] => http://www.cfcarehospitalar.com.br/
    )

[Vary] => Array
    (
        [0] => Accept-Encoding
        [1] => Accept-Encoding
        [2] => Accept-Encoding
        [3] => Accept-Encoding
    )

[Content-Length] => Array
    (
        [0] => 375
        [1] => 370
    )

[Connection] => Array
    (
        [0] => close
        [1] => close
        [2] => close
        [3] => close
    )

[Content-Type] => Array
    (
        [0] => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
        [1] => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
        [2] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
        [3] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    )

[1] => HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
[2] => HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
[X-Powered-By] => Array
    (
        [0] => PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze19
        [1] => PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze19
    )

[Expires] => Array
    (
        [0] => Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
        [1] => Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    )

[Cache-Control] => Array
    (
        [0] => no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
        [1] => no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    )

[Pragma] => Array
    (
        [0] => no-cache
        [1] => no-cache
    )

[Set-Cookie] => Array
    (
        [0] => frontend=g42hn3qgu179rib57kot3looa4; expires=Sat, 30-May-2015 10:38:18 GMT; path=/; domain=www.cfcarehospitalar.com.br; HttpOnly
        [1] => frontend=m9fsajlpkf6svr0ejaojr1v205; expires=Sat, 30-May-2015 10:38:19 GMT; path=/; domain=www.cfcarehospitalar.com.br; HttpOnly
    )

[3] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
)
```

Comment: Well, you set `$i` to 0. `$count_location` is going to be 0 or more. Your for condition is `$i > $count_location` which is never going to happen.

Comment: Print your array using `print_r($urls_array)` and put the output here so that we can have more idea of what you're talking about. Also `$i` should not be in quotes when you're trying to echo the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have mistake in your for loop, it should be

```
for ($i=0; $i < $count_location ; $i++) { 
          echo $urls_array["Location"]["$i"];
      }
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake! I can't believe I didn't saw such a thing... lol